# Spring-boot JPA multiple data-sources is not updating or creating tables

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, groovy

I am facing a problem with JPA with spring-boot with `multiple data-sources`. It is something I have always managed to do. But this time I cannot understand why is not working?

After gradle build or bootRun no table is being created or updated. No compile or run time errors at startup. I am losing my mind.

You can find my code attached.

P2BDatabaseConfig.groovy

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "p2bEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "p2bTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"it.project.sol.sharpapi.repo.p2b"}
)
public class P2BDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean(name = "p2bDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.p2b")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "p2bPU")
    @Bean(name = "p2bEntityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean p2bEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                          @Qualifier("p2bDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("it.project.sol.sharpapi.entity.p2b").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "p2bTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager p2bTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("p2bEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory p2bEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(p2bEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

SharpDatabaseConfig.groovy

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "sharpEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "sharpTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"it.project.sol.sharpapi.repo.sharp"}
)
public class SharpDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean(name = "sharpDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.sharp")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sharpPU")
    @Bean(name = "sharpEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sharpEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                          @Qualifier("sharpDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("it.project.sol.sharpapi.entity.sharp").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sharpTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager sharpTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("sharpEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory sharpEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(sharpEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: Developement

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

  p2b:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/p2bv2?autoReconnect=true
    username: xxxx
    password: xxxx!
    testWhileIdle: true
    maxActive: 5
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  sharp:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sharp?autoReconnect=true
    username: xxxx
    password: xxxx!
    testWhileIdle: true
    maxActive: 5
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

P2BDevice.groovy

```
@Entity(name = "P2BDevice")
@Table(name = "device")
class P2BDevice implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id

    @Column(name = "version")
    Long version

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    Date dateCreated

    @Column(name = "deleted")
    int deleted

    @Column(name = "description")
    String description

    ...

}
```

User.groovy

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "caccapupu")
class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id

    @Column(name = "version")
    Long version

    @Column(name = "username")
    String username

    @Column(name = "password")
    Long password

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    Date dateCreated

    @Column(name = "status")
    int status

    ...

}
```

I can assure you, repositories are correct and even the packages position of my classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to explicitly set JPA properties

```
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = 
builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("it.project.sol.sharpapi.entity.sharp").build();
            HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
            properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
            em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
```

Comment: This works, thanks! But i cannot understand why it isn't picking these properties automatically from my application.yml

Comment: I don't know how spring-boot bootstrapping JPA inside, maybe it's can't mix java configuration with yml/prop or it works only for default JPA bean name i.e "entityManagerFactory"